# What are the advantages of websocket APIs to middleware?

Tags: websocket, middleware, hivemq

Some pieces of middleware support websockets natively e.g. HiveMQ: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-over-websockets-with-hivemq/. What advantages are conferred to a developer using the websockets API as a first class client to the middleware, rather than routing requests through an intermediary server that supports language specific APIs e.g.

Client -> Middleware

vs

Client -> Server -> Middleware

For example, we could argue that skipping an intermediary server will reduce bandwidth costs, not require a developer to write an extra layer, native SSL websockets support?

What other advantages might be provided to not just a developer, but any party through providing websockets support for middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage you get is **simplicity** and in case of HiveMQ, **scalability**.

Let me explain these advantages:

### Simplicity

In case of HiveMQ, you just start the server and you are good to go. All web applications which use a MQTT library over websockets can connect to the server without even knowing that websockets as transport is used. For HiveMQ itself, it's just another MQTT client. So it doesn't matter if the clients are connected via websockets or via a classic TCP connection. I think you already mentioned the other arguments in your question. And of course last but not least the operations guys will thank you if they have one system (in your case the "Server") less to maintain.

### Scalability

Software like HiveMQ is very scalable and it can handle up to hundreds of thousands of concurrent connected clients. The chance is high, that the additional layer ("Server" in your case) could introduce a bottleneck. Also, things like load balancing with a HW or SW load balancer gets a lot easier if you can throw out unneeded layers. In general, your architecture of your system will get a lot of easier if you don't need these additional layers (which are *not* services which can be reused for other applications, like microservices are).

---

Last but not least it's worth noting, that HiveMQ itself is often integrated with classic middleware / ESBs. That means, people write custom plugins for integrating HiveMQ to their existing middleware. JMS or webservice calls (REST, SOAP) are often used for doing that.

Take that answer with a grain of salt, since I'm involved developing HiveMQ :-)